# Double an array size by altering its values in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a sting like so:

```
string searches = "my test";
```

And then I can break them into individual terms like so:

```
string[] split = searches.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
```

This gives me:

```
[0] = "my"
[1] = "test"
```

Is there any quick way to make the following:

```
[0] = "my"
[1] = "test"
[2] = "my:"
[3] = "test:"
[4] = "my,"
[5] = "test,"
```

I need to double the search terms and append a ":" to the end of the doubled set. What's the easiest and efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to do it is just use unions:

```
            string searches = "my test";
            var split = searches.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
            var modifiedArray1 = split.Select(x => x + ":");
            var modifiedArray2 = split.Select(x => x + ",");
            split = split.Union(modifiedArray1).ToArray().Union(modifiedArray2).ToArray();
            foreach (var s in split)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is quick and dirty LINQ. If you have a variety of stuff to append, you can leverage an array of what you want to append and a trusty FOR loop.

```
string[] stuffToAppend = new String[]{ ":", "," };

string[] split = searches.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
List<String> newStrings = new List<String>(split);
foreach( String append in stuffToAppend )
    newStrings.AddRange( split.Select( s => s + append ) );
```

You can now get the new array via newStrings.ToArray() if you really need an array.

Comment: Maybe you can add some explanation and links to MSDN?

Comment: hmm what if I needed to add ":" and "," to split?

Comment: Updated the code. The stuffToAppend array contains the individual values you want to append to your source array (split).